# Use Microsoft Graph Core Python Client Library with the Azure Active Directory App registration (client id & secret)

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The documentation and the examples of the [Microsoft Graph Core Python Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core) shows only the usage with `InteractiveBrowserCredential`.

```py
# python -m pip install msgraph-core
# python -m pip install azure-identity

from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

browser_credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
client = GraphClient(credential=browser_credential)
result = client.get('/me')
print(result.json())
```

How is it possible to use the `GraphClient` without interaction by providing the `cleint id` and `secret` of the Azure Active Directory App registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following URL to configure your Azure Active Directory App registration: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

The Python library ["Azure Identity client library for Python (azure-identity)"](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) offers several authentication options. 
["Authenticate service principals"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-python) could be used to achieve the authentication with the Azure Active Directory App registration without any interaction.

```py
# python -m pip install msgraph-core
# python -m pip install azure-identity

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

client_secret_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id='XXX',
    client_id='XXX',
    client_secret='XXX')

client = GraphClient(credential=client_secret_credential)

result = client.get(
    '/groups',
    params={
        '$select': 'displayName',
        '$top': '10'
    },
)
pprint(result.json())
```